# How to access Apache VirtualHost via both Name & IP

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I am using Apache VirtualHosts with 2 local domains on my home computer for development & testing.

```
• d4damage.local (personal websites)

• company.local (work stuff on external drive)
```

It's working perfectly on my network. However, I also need to optionally access `d4damage.local` via IP `192.168.1.60` (my computer is fixed to this IP)

The reason is my PS3 cannot resolve `d4damage.local`, but it can via IP. (all my other wi-fi devices are fine using `d4damage.local`)

It seems I can set `d4damage.local` to work on IP or name, but not both. (403 forbidden) the commented lines show the alternatives.

*httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
#NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.60:80
#<VirtualHost 192.168.1.60:80>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@d4damage.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/paul/Sites"
    ServerName d4damage.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/d4damage.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/d4damage.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

*httpd.conf*

```
ServerName d4damage.local
...
DocumentRoot "/Users/paul/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/paul/Sites">
```

*hosts*

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
192.168.1.60 company.local d4damage.local 
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost 
::1 localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

The above files concern the main domain i wish to use on my computer, the `company.local` one is additional & i don't need to access that via IP.

Hope you can help! Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: with `ServerName d4damage.local` in http.conf & VirtualHosts OFF - I can access via IP & name on any device. But by activating VirtualHosts I lose the ability to access via IP.

Comment: I haven't tested your case but you shouldn't comment the `NameVirtualHost` line when you use VirtualHosts. You can use `NameVirtualHost *:80`. Also I don't think you need the `ServerName` in httpd.conf when you are using VirtualHost.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried both, neither makes a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will want to edit your hosts file, commonly found ´/etc/hosts´.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and new line like this:

```
192.168.1.60  d4damage.local
```

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: That does not work, it seems to have no effect. Although currently in hosts file i have `127.0.0.1       localhost company.local` which does work for company.local on this machine only (as intended)

Comment: It was my own fault to leave dummy-host.example.com in the config file, so your answer would have worked i believe. thanks.

Comment: @Faron updating hosts file not require to reboot web server.

Answer (score 0):

ah ha! I have found the issue. 
I had (carelessly) left the example vhosts `dummy-host.example.com` in the vhosts file & simply commenting that block out has fixed the problem. I assume that because the dummy name/directory is not defined in httpd.conf & therefore causes a misconfiguration.

So the answer is to make sure you remove or comment-out the dummy examples in httpd-vhosts.conf